# Set JsonSerializerSettings Per Response?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-web-api

I have an MVC 4 Web API. Usually I want responses to return all properties, but there is one place I only want to return only non-null values. I can setup either behavior by setting the JsonSerializerSettings of the `Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling` of the `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration` instance in the global file but I want to use both depending on the response. Is there an easy way to configure the request scope from within an API controller action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By changing your controller action to return HttpResponseMessage you can get more control over how your content is returned for a particular action.  e.g.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get() {
   var foo = new Foo();

   var objectContent = new ObjectContent<Foo>(foo, new JsonFormatter()
                                {SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = ???})

    return new HttpResponseMessage() {Content = objectContent};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this would probably be easier to do on the client side with a dynamic language like javascript.

```
var keys = Object.keys(json);
for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var propertyName = keys[i];
    if(json[propertyName] === undefined || v[propertyName] === null) {
           json.remove(propertyName);
    }
}
return json;
```

Comment: That's not even necessary. In this case I'm just trying to cull a large amount of data being sent over a slow connection.

Comment: Besides that I can imagine wanting to alter other serialization options in the future that are not so easily enforced on the client.